# Glm Quaternion lookat function

Tags: c++, opengl, quaternions, glm-math

I am trying to write a lookat function that uses glm::quat to represent rotations, based of off this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17654730/771790). I am running into trouble getting a correct angle however. This is my lookat function:

```
void Camera::LookAt(float x, float y, float z) {
    glm::vec3 lookVector = glm::vec3(x, y, z);
    assert(lookVector != position);

    glm::vec3 direction = glm::normalize(lookVector-position);
    float dot = glm::dot(glm::vec3(0, 0, -1), direction);
    if (fabs(dot - (-1.0f)) < 0.000001f)
        rotation = glm::quat(RadiansToDegrees(M_PI), 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    if (fabs(dot - (1.0f)) < 0.000001f)
        rotation = glm::quat();

    float angle = RadiansToDegrees(acosf(dot));

    glm::vec3 cross = (glm::cross(glm::vec3(0, 0, -1), direction));
    rotation = glm::normalize(glm::angleAxis(angle, cross));

    std::cout << glm::eulerAngles(rotation).x  << " " << glm::eulerAngles(rotation).y << " " << glm::eulerAngles(rotation).z << "\n";
}
```

When I call LookAt(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f) when my camera is at (0.0f, 0.0f, -10.0f), this outputs a correct rotation of 0,0,0. However if I translate my camera to (0.0f, -0.01f, -10.0f) or more I get a rotation of about 124,0,0. This goes down if I continue to translate y by -0.01f. If I do not normalize the quaternion I do not get this problem. The rotation is still 124 about the x axis, but the appearance is fine. If however I normalize the quaternion later it once again appears to rotate to about 124. I can not normalize `cross`, because doing so throws an assert. What would cause me to get euler angles of 124 about x from my lookat function, and how can I fix it?

Comment: As the [GLM documentation](http://glm.g-truc.net/api-0.9.4/a00153.html#gaafc03953867e42a39dc08575ad4532ad) says, the axis for `glm::angleAxis` must be normalized, which it is not in your case. What kind of assert is thrown when you try to normalize `cross`? As long as `direction` is not parallel to `(0, 0, -1)` there should be no problem.

Comment: Debugging the code, I just realized that cross is `(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f)` which explains the assert which is thrown from inversesrt.

Comment: Ah.. In this case `dot == -1` and `rotation` is already set. However, you try to calculate it again, which makes no sense. So just add an `else` block.

Comment: Now rotation is about `(180, 0, 0)`. This is still not looking at `(0,0,0)`

Comment: That's what you defined in the first case. You probably wanted to use `angleAxis()` again instead of the pure constructor.

Comment: I think that the pure constructor is what the person in the answer I linked to meant. In the if statement he returns a pure constructor quaternion, while for other cases he returns the equivalent of angleAxis(). In any case if I use angleAxis I get `(180, 0, 180)`.

Comment: And `(180, 0, 180)` is correct, isn't it? This would be equal to `(0, 180, 0)`. The original direction of `(0, 0, 1)` is correctly rotated to `(0, 0, -1)`. If, however, you want to look in positive z-direction, you will have to change the vectors accordingly.

Answer (score 8):

Since version 0.9.9.0 there is a function in `<glm/gtc/quaternion.hpp>` doing mostly what you want:

```
template<typename T, qualifier Q>
tquat<T, Q> quatLookAt(vec<3, T, Q> const& direction, vec<3, T, Q> const& up);
```

It was added by [this pull request](https://github.com/g-truc/glm/pull/659) and has been merged into master July 24, 2017.

**But**:

1. direction has to be a normalized vector!
2. direction can't be parallel to up!

So you may want to write a safer wrapper around the function:

```
glm::quat safeQuatLookAt(
    glm::vec3 const& lookFrom,
    glm::vec3 const& lookTo,
    glm::vec3 const& up,
    glm::vec3 const& alternativeUp)
{
    glm::vec3  direction       = lookTo - lookFrom;
    float      directionLength = glm::length(direction);

    // Check if the direction is valid; Also deals with NaN
    if(!(directionLength > 0.0001))
        return glm::quat(1, 0, 0, 0); // Just return identity

    // Normalize direction
    direction /= directionLength;

    // Is the normal up (nearly) parallel to direction?
    if(glm::abs(glm::dot(direction, up)) > .9999f) {
        // Use alternative up
        return glm::quatLookAt(direction, alternativeUp);
    }
    else {
        return glm::quatLookAt(direction, up);
    }
}
```

Comment: If the direction and up vector are parallel, then what should alternative up be?

Comment: @TomH Literally any vector that isn't parallel to up. I often just use a vector along the X or Z-Axis if I think "up" and "direction" will rarely become parallel. 
For game characters, a vector pointing to the back of the character is a good choice, since "alternativeUp" is basically what the top of their head will point to when they look straight upwards.

Answer (score 2):

I have fixed the problem with the following code:

```
void Camera::LookAt(float x, float y, float z) {
    glm::vec3 lookVector = glm::vec3(x, y, z);
    assert(lookVector != position);

    glm::vec3 direction = glm::normalize(lookVector-position);
    float dot = glm::dot(glm::vec3(0, 0, 1), direction);
    if (fabs(dot - (-1.0f)) < 0.000001f) {
        rotation = glm::angleAxis(RadiansToDegrees(M_PI), glm::vec3(0, 1, 0));
        return;
    }
    else if (fabs(dot - (1.0f)) < 0.000001f) {
        rotation = glm::quat();
        return;
    }

    float angle = -RadiansToDegrees(acosf(dot));

    glm::vec3 cross = glm::normalize(glm::cross(glm::vec3(0, 0, 1), direction));
    rotation = glm::normalize(glm::angleAxis(angle, cross));
}
```

I do not however understand the necessity of the negative on `angle`. It fixed the last of my problems, and an explanation of the math of why would be helpful.

Comment: That's because your axis points in the wrong direction. You could also do `cross = glm::normalize(glm::cross(direction, glm::vec3(0, 0, 1)))`. Btw, `glm::angleAxis()` probably already returns a normalized quaternion.