# glm::quatLookAt Return a NaN quaternion

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math

I have a LookAt function (taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18172388/glm-quaternion-lookat-function)) which calculate a Quaternion :

```
Camera& Camera::LookAt(const glm::vec3& lookat)noexcept{
   glm::vec3  direction = lookat - transform.GetPosition();
   float directionLength = glm::length(direction);

   if(!(directionLength > 0.0001)){ // Check if the direction is valid; Also deals with NaN
       transform.SetRotation(glm::quat(1, 0, 0, 0));
       return *this;
   }
   direction /= directionLength; // Normalize direction

   if(glm::abs(glm::dot(direction, transform.GetWorldUp())) > .9999f) {
       transform.SetRotation(glm::inverse(glm::quatLookAt(direction, transform.GetUp())));// Use relative up
   } else {
       transform.SetRotation(glm::inverse(glm::quatLookAt(direction, transform.GetWorldUp())));
   }
   return *this;
}
```

For some reason, when camera first position is 0 0 20 (with a quaternion of 1 0 0 0) and I change it to 0 20 0 and call LookAt() my quaternions end up with only NaN. If camera first position is not 0 0 20 (or 20 0 0) it work fine.

Here is my console (I added few std::cout to LookAt function and before my transformation) :[image: Invalide quaternion]

I have no idea of what happening, Can someone help me ?

EDIT :

Here is the new function I have writed, it check if both direction are parrallel. If it is, it change the direction a bit to prevent parallel :

```
Camera& Camera::LookAt(const glm::vec3& lookat)noexcept{
    glm::vec3 direction = glm::normalize( lookat - transform.GetPosition());
    if(!(glm::length(direction) > 0.0001)){ // Check if the direction is valid; Also deals with NaN
        transform.SetRotation(glm::quat(1, 0, 0, 0));
        return *this;
    }
    //Check if We must use relative Up
    glm::vec3 upToUse = transform.GetWorldUp();
    if(glm::abs(glm::dot(direction, transform.GetWorldUp())) > .9999f) upToUse = transform.GetUp();
    //Check if parallel
    if(glm::vec3(0.0f) == glm::cross(transform.GetUp(),direction) ) direction = glm::normalize(lookat - (transform.GetPosition() + glm::vec3(0.001f,0.0f,0.001f))); //Change position and recalculate direction
    //Calcul new quaternion
    transform.SetRotation(glm::inverse(glm::quatLookAt(direction, upToUse)));
    return *this;
 }
```

Comment: What is the up vector? You didn't print it

Comment: @user253751 before LookAt call : 0 1 0

Comment: @Rabbid76 actually the second one is the "up vector", not the rotation axis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are asking GLM to create a quaternion that will make the Z direction (0, -1, 0) (the direction vector) and the Y direction also (0, 1, 0) (the up vector).

This is impossible. No amount of rotation will make the Y and Z axes point in opposite directions from each other. You need to specify a different up vector.

Note that the up vector doesn't have to be perpendicular to the direction vector, because GLM will ignore the part that isn't perpendicular. But it has to be *at least a little bit* perpendicular.

Comment: I got it Thanks !